# C++ virtual method with class specific parameter

Tags: c++, object, methods, virtual

Hi I have such an idea in my mind, but I don't know how to implement it. In my program I already have Base class, and few derived classes.

```
base.hpp
BaseClass {
 public:
   BaseClass();
   virtual int getSomething(int param);
}

base.cpp
BaseClass::BaseClass(){};
int BaseClass::getSomething(int param)
{
  return param * 5;
}

derived1.hpp
DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
 public: 
  DerivedClass1();
}

derived2.hpp
DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass {
 public: 
  DerivedClass1();
}
```

Now I use Derived or Base classes as needed.

```
BaseClass *c = (BaseClass *) new DerivedClass1;
cout << c->getSomething(5);
```

What I want is to have some type of class specific parameter in base class, which would be different for DerivedClass1 and DerivedClass2. Here is an example, how it could look like.

```
base.hpp
BaseClass {
 public:
  BaseClass();
  virtual int getSomething(int param);
}

base.cpp
BaseClass::BaseClass(){};
int BaseClass::getSomething(int param)
{
  return param * CLASS_SPECIFIC_PARAM;
}
```

Then for DerivedClass1 this CLASS_SPECIFIC_PARAM would be 5, for DerivedClass2 would be 6 or whatever.
Is this even possible to do ? What is the best approach to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add a parameter to your base class which children will reset on their own values:

**base.hpp**

```
BaseClass {
 public:
   BaseClass() : m_param(0) {};
   virtual int getSomething(int param);
 protected:
   int m_param;
}
```

**derived1.hpp**

```
DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
 public: 
  DerivedClass1() : m_param(5) {};
}
```

**derived2.hpp**

```
DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass {
 public: 
  DerivedClass1() : m_param(6) {};
}
```

PS: And add a virtual destructor to your `BaseClass`

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be a virtual (or pure virtual function) instead of a protected member.

```
BaseClass {
 public:
   BaseClass();
   virtual int getSomething(int param);
 protected:
   virtual int getClassSpecific() const =0;
}
//...
BaseClass::BaseClass(){};
int BaseClass::getSomething(int param)
{
  return param * getClassSpecific();
}

//...
DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
 //...
 virtual int getClassSpecific() const { return 5;}
}

//.....
DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass {
 //...
 virtual int getClassSpecific() const { return 6;}
}
```